# How do you apply a filter at runtime with a node.js Azure Function hitting Table Storage?

Tags: node.js, azure-table-storage, azure-functions

I'm writing an Azure Function to access multiple records in Azure Table Storage and want to apply my filter at runtime with a variable passed in to a WebHook.  I have successfully run my Function with the filter in function.js, but don't see anything in the docs on how to apply the filter inside index.js.

I tried this, but it had no effect on the entities returned.  This same filter works correctly inside function.js.

```
context.bindings.inputTable.filter = 'name eq "test"';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't construct and set the filter in your function code. We do have an open issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/85) in our repo tracking support for more dynamic binding scenarios, which would enable this.

However, the `function.json` filter expression **does** support binding parameters, so if the parameters are part of the JSON payload coming in on the WebHook you can use them in your query. For example, if your payload contains properties `region` of type string and `status` of type int you can define a filter like `"(Region eq '{region}') and (Status eq {status})"` and the filter executed at runtime will be bound to the incoming values.

Comment: Thank you very much.  It would be awesome if this was added to the docs :)

Comment: Most of the various binding properties support binding expressions. However, I've logged a doc bug [here](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/81) to make this more obvious.

Comment: 2 years later and the issue is still open. It would clearly add a lot of usefulness to functions.